# Mono Compatibility with Enterprise Library 4.1

Tags: mono, enterprise-library

Does anybody using latest enterprise library 4.1 in mono? I used mono migration analyzer to analyze my web application and realized all enterprise library dll is failed in mono.

I need to know is that true that enterprise library 4.1 is not compatible in mono 2.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ent Lib 4.1 is not mono compatible yet. I will have to switch my plan to not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I have an update on this.

**[Enterprise Library 4.0 now Open Source](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-09.html)**

Answer (score 1):

I initially played a little with getting EntLib 4.0 to run on Mono:
http://jpobst.blogspot.com/2008/10/smart-client-software-factory-on-mono.html

I don't know if anyone has tried EntLib 4.1.  Unfortunately, I know nothing about EntLib other than trying to get that sample to work.  It seemed extremely complex.

Probably the best way to find out would be to try running you application on Mono and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Unity is not yet Mono friendly.

Remember that you can always use Moma to check those DLLs.

I think both parties (MS and Novell) need to work closely to address those remaining issues.

Comment: Unity? I guess that is a typo

Comment: @knocte Microsoft Unity, not the Unity3D.

Comment: how is MS Unity container related to MS Enterprise Libraries? excuse my ignorance please

Comment: @knocte staring from a certain version, all EntLib bits depend on that Unity to do configuration and so on.