# missing assembly reference Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary in Mono/.NET 4.0

Tags: .net, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

I am new to .NET

Currently trying to load a project in Xamarin Studio and when I am trying to build the project. I ran into an error that is missing assembly reference.

How can I add Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary in Mono?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924832/mono-compatibility-with-enterprise-library-4-1/1062529

Comment: While this Q/A is old, it is still mostly true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924832/mono-compatibility-with-enterprise-library-4-1/1062529 Also see the EnterpriseServices section of http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/ As a personal opinion note, the MPE is a "heavy" framework and while great on desktops, it would be a memory/perf killer on mobile

Answer (score 0):

Entlib is not compatible with mono. And is a perf killer. Forget it for mobile apps.